# How release file when exception occur during file copy in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

When exception occur during file copy in c# that source file is cannot access again because file was not released by the File.Copy() method.This is the simple code which i use to copy file from one location to a another.

```
 File.Copy(filePath, Address + "\\" + fileName, true);
```

After exception occur i cannot access to source file again.

what is the solution for this problem. Are there any methods to release file again?

Answer (score 0):

Call following line in finally block, so it will release the handle as file is copied successfully or error is raised.

```
try
{
File.Copy(filePath, Address + "\\" + fileName, true);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
        new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission
    (System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] 
    { filePath}).Demand();
}
```